# Issues selecting class in table

Tags: jquery

I am just diving into jquery, so please excuse any really silly mistakes...

I have a table I am generating from a database.

```
<table id="DataTable">
    <tr>
        <th><input type="button" onclick=doCheck()></th>
        <th>col 2</th>
        <th>col 3</th>
        <th>col 4</th>
        <th>col 5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
        <td>data 2</td>
        <td>data 3</td>
        <td>data 4</td>
        <td class="thisOne">data 5</td>
    </tr>
 .
 .
 .
  </table>
```

I need to perform some validation checks on column5, labeled `thisOne`, based on whether or not it is in a row where the box is checked. Here is what I have so far:

```
//Get checkboxes
var boxes = $("#DataTable").find("tr td input[type=checkbox]");
var locations = [];
boxes.each(function (index, element) {
        if ($(element).is(':checked')) {
            //Code here
        }
    });
```

In the area marked `//code here` I have tried many things and have not been able to successfully select the column I want. Some things I have tried (NOTE: I am using `Hide()` for testing purposes):

```
$(this).closest("td").next('.thisOne').hide(); Doesn't work
$(this).parent("td").next('.thisOne').hide();  Doesn't Work
$(this).closest("td").hide();                  Works as expected
$(this).closest("td").next().hide();           Works as expected
$('.thisOne').hide();                          Works as expected
```

Shouldn't the first line I listed work? `.closest()` will navigate up to the `td` level, where `.next('thisOne')` will traverse the DOM until a `td` tag with that class is found? Please explain any answers as I am really curious as to why this is not working. Thanks

Comment: Maybe a typo, but did you mean `$("#datatable")`?

Comment: Typo is correct. My mistake. Fixing..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings)

```
$(this).closest('td').siblings('.thisOne').hide();
```

---

Also since `#datatable` is a table, you do not need to specify `tr td`.. just go for the checkbox..

```
var boxes = $("#dataTable :checkbox");
```

Finally `checked` is also a property of the checkbox, so no need to query for it through jQuery.. You can use `element.checked`.

Altogether

```
var boxes = $("#dataTable :checkbox");
var locations = [];
boxes.each(function () {
        if ( this.checked ) {
            //Code here
            $(this).closest('td').siblings('.thisOne').hide();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var boxes = $("#DataTable :checkbox");
$.each(boxes, function() {
    if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) {             
        $(this).closest('td').siblings('.thisOne').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The line you are looking for should look something like this -

```
$(element).closest('tr').find('td.thisOne');
```

Lets break it down,

1. `$(element)` - the checkbox itself.
2. [`closest('tr')`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) the closest parent element that is a `<tr>`.
3. [`find('td.thisOne')`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) - from within that parent element, find the `<td>` element with the `thisOne` class.

```
//Get checkboxes
var boxes = $("#DataTable").find("tr td input[type=checkbox]");
var locations = [];
boxes.each(function (index, element) {
  if ($(element).is(':checked')) {
    var thatOne = $(element).closest('tr').find('td.thisOne');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question:

[`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) does not work because it **only** finds the next sibling.

For your case, you need [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/), which finds **all following siblings**, i.e.

```
$(this).closest("td").nextAll('.thisOne').hide();
```

Detailed breakdown:

```
$(this)                // This is your checkbox.
.closest("td")         // This gets its closest ancester "td".
.nextAll('.thisOne')   // This finds the closest following sibling that has the class "thisOne".
.hide();
```

Working demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tr53C/1/).